# how to get a list of only excel file with its ModifiedDate in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using below batch file to get coma separated list of file with its complete path and modified date in next column. how to get a list of only excel file?

```
@Powershell -NoP -C "GCI $(GCI \"H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\"|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,LastwriteTime|Export-csv -NoT \"C:\MoldPara\Bhavesh.csv\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` (aka `gci`) has a filter parameter you can use to filter for Excel file extensions. (xls or xlsx):

```
Get-ChildItem 'H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\' -filter *.xls*
```

So the modified version of your script would be:

```
@Powershell -NoP -C "GCI $(GCI \"H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\" -filter *.xls* |?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,LastwriteTime|Export-csv -NoT \"C:\MoldPara\Bhavesh.csv\""
```

However, I would recommend rewriting it like this to make it more readable:

```
Get-ChildItem 'H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\' -filter *.xls* -File -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,LastwriteTime | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\MoldPara\Bhavesh.csv'
```

or wrapped in an external PowerShell command like you had it:

```
@Powershell -NoP -C "Get-ChildItem 'H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\' -filter *.xls* -File -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,LastwriteTime | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\MoldPara\Bhavesh.csv'"
```

I'm making use of single quotes to avoid having to escape double quotes.  You can use single quotes when you do not have variables in your strings and also making use of these two switches:

- `-File` = Only returns files (you can also use -Directory for directories). Introduced in PowerShell 3.
- `-Recurse` = Recursively iterate through directories (Which you were already using)

Comment: Now only files are coming which made my list more pure for my requirement  -  THANK YOU VERY MUCH for additional recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-filter` parameter to the Get-ChildItem statement for that, so you end up with

```
@Powershell -NoP -C "GCI $(GCI \"H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\" -filter *.xlsx|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,LastwriteTime|Export-csv -NoT \"C:\MoldPara\Bhavesh.csv\""
```

would give you all .xlsx files, or more broadly you could use `-filter *.xls*` to also include .xls, xlsm etc files in case you have any.